# How to Set Uniform Sampler in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm trying to understand uniform samplers and textures in GLSL. Right now, I understand basic uniforms, in that if I have

```
uniform float someFloat;
```

in my shader, I would write (pseudocode) such as

```
someFloatLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "someFloat")
glUniform1f(someFloatLoc, 3.14159)
```

to set the value of the uniform.

However, if I instead have

```
uniform shader1d t1;
uniform shader2d t2;
```

in my shader, what is the corresponding OpenGL function to set the texture? I would expect to find something like `glUniformshader2d(uniform_loc, texture)` wherein `texture` is an array specifying the texture, but so far my research leads me to a large number of functions, like `glActiveTexture`, `glGenTextures`, `glBindTextures`, `glTexImage2d`, and constants like `GL_TEXTURE1`. But all I'm trying to do is assign an array specifying the texture to a specific shader `uniform samplerXd foo` so I then can compute the output color based on `fetchTexel(foo, texture_coord)`.

My question can be summarized as follows:

**How can I mimic the functionality of `glUniform1f` for a uniform float in a GLSL shader, but for a uniform sampler instead?**

Comment: "*wherein `texture` is an array specifying the texture*" Why would it be an array?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas - the goal is to use the texture and the texelFetch method is to be able to quickly pass a large 2D array to the shader, which is then used to computer the color of a fragment. I have read there is a size limit on arrays of uniforms so basically I am trying to use the texture as a "unlimited" size array of uniforms.

Comment: My point was about your use of the term "an array specifying the texture". That suggests that the variable named `texture` is an array of some kind, rather than the GLuint name of a texture. It's still doesn't work; you don't pass textures directly to shaders. But what you're trying to pass isn't an array variable.

Comment: @NicolBolas - "you don't pass textures directly to shaders" So where does a shader get a texture if it isn't passed to it? Apparently I'm misunderstanding something here. I thought uniforms were variables passed to shaders?

Comment: see [Texturing a cube with different images using OpenGL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65276638/2521214) ... sampler is just single integer representing which texture unit to use ... so you should use `glUniform1i`

Comment: some more info about purpose of code, could be much helpful.